# powershell: run code when importing module

Tags: powershell

I have developed a powershell module in C#, implemented a few commands.

How can I execute C# code in this module when it's imported by Powershell?

Comment: You want you binary(c#) powershell-module to run some code when it's imported? Unclear question. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Correct, I want to execute C# code in my module when it's imported by powershell. I want to do some initiation stuff. And "when it's imported by powershell" -> when executing command: Import-Module .\MyModule.dll

Answer (score 6):

Create a module manifest with the ModuleToProcess (or RootModule in V3) field set to the PSM1 file and the NestedModules set to the DLL e.g.:

```
RootModule         = 'Pscx.psm1'
NestedModules      = 'Pscx.dll'
```

This is what we do in the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) where we do the same thing - fire up a script first.  You can see our PSD1 file [here](http://pscx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/100892#1357945).

Comment: Do I need to sign the assembly with signtool, or how does the psd1 file become embedded into the dll file?

Comment: You don't embed the PSD1 in the DLL. You ship a module as a collection of files in a folder e.g. PSCX\pscx.psd1, PSCX\pscx.psm1, PSCX\pscx.dll, etc.  And you don't have to Authenticode sign anything.

Comment: I use exactly this approach, but then the module auto-loading does not work. My users must explicitly run Import-Module before first use. When I keep RootModule empty, auto-loading just works. Do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic solution, simply replace code within the {} with your source. (my test below)

add-type 'public class c{public const string s="Hello World";}';[c]::s

enjoy

Comment: Are you suggesting to explicit execute a function after import?

Comment: I'm not a c# developer by any stretch of the imagination. But when I write my powershell modules when you import the module the code not wrapped in a function or workflow is executed as soon as it loads. I cannot be sure this is the case with a C# module.

Comment: I don't think there's anything that corresponds to trailing script code in a C# module.

Comment: Keith Hill has it on the nose, ModuleToProcess, my first logical step would have been script to process, this is an excerpt from my Module Manifest. 
# Script files (.ps1) that are run in the caller's environment prior to importing this module.
# ScriptsToProcess = @()

Answer (score 0):

I'm also writing a binary cmdLet in .NET.  I have found that if you create a class that inherits from at least DriveCmdletProvider, that class can implement InitializeDefaultDrives.

This method will get call when import-module is called on your DLL.

You could use this 'feature' to stand up some session (or module session) data.