# Binary Cmdlet Formatting File

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am developing my first PowerShell binary module using C#. The cmdlet is basic, it will connect to our production servers and list the status of the services.

I would like to output the `MachineName` property along with the default `Status`, `Name` and `DisplayName` properties. (I can do `Get-AppService | select MachineName,Status,Name` to accomplish this.)

I have read about using a `.format.ps1xml` file, which I have written:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <ViewDefinitions>
    <View>
      <Name>service</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <TableControl>
        <TableHeaders>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>20</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>8</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>18</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>38</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
        </TableHeaders>
        <TableRowEntries>
          <TableRowEntry>
            <TableColumnItems>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>MachineName</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Status</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>DisplayName</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
            </TableColumnItems>
          </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
      </TableControl>
    </View>
  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

I don't know where to put this so that it applies to only my cmdlet. Right now I am using `Import-Module` to pull in my DLL from Visual Studio's bin\Debug folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Update-FormatData and point it to your .format.ps1xml file. [Link to TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849884.aspx)

Update: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14611496/1613873) answer he explains how to run a script when your c# module is loaded.

Comment: Legend, that's exactly what I needed to know. Thank you.